# Using \snoc as macro name inside mathpar

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors

I'm able to define a macro called `\snoc` but unable to use it inside a `mathpar` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\newcommand{\snoc}{hi}

\begin{document}
\begin{mathpar}
\inferrule
{
}
{
   \snoc
}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \snoc has an extra }.
```

If I rename the macro to `\noc` (for example) it works fine. Is `\snoc` some sort of reserved word in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `mathpartir` defines `\snoc` *inside* the `mathpar` environment, overriding whatever definition you give outside.

Yes, it *is* a reserved command, although I couldn't find any trace of this in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, Googling for `mathpartir` and `snoc` does show `snoc` making an appearance, but it's not documented, nor is the error message particularly informative.